# R: how to create an object of class "rq" manually?

Tags: r, class, predict, quantreg

How can I create manually an object of class "rq" such that I can use it afterwards to run the `predict` function?

Thanks to your very useful replies, `mymdl` is now of class "rq" in this example. Adding `class(mymdl$coefficients) ="numeric"` to the code solved my main issue: `predict(mymdl)` works.

Interestingly enough, `class(mdl$terms)` and `class(mymdl$terms)` differ. If I set `class(mymdl$terms) = class(mdl$terms)`, then `predict(mymdl)` produces `NAs`. I am wondering why this is happening..

```
library(quantreg)

data(engel)                                 #load dataset
engel2 <- engel[1:100,]                     #keep subset for prediction
reg_formula <- foodexp ~ income             #define regression formula
mdl <- rq(reg_formula,.5, data = engel)     #run regression

#------------------------------------------
#remove non-essential information from mdl
#mdl$coefficients <- NULL
mdl$x <- NULL
mdl$y <- NULL
mdl$residuals <- NULL
mdl$dual <- NULL
mdl$fitted.values <- NULL
mdl$formula <- NULL
#mdl$terms <- NULL
mdl$xlevels <- NULL
mdl$call <- NULL
mdl$tau <- NULL
mdl$rho <- NULL
mdl$method <- NULL
mdl$model <- NULL

#Only mdl$coefficients and mdl$terms are
#essential for predicting
#------------------------------------------

engel2$foodexp_pr <- predict(mdl, newdata = engel2) #predict


#create own regression model
mymdl <- NULL
mymdl[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]] <- 81.48225
mymdl[["coefficients"]][["income"]] <- 0.5601806
mymdl$terms <- reg_formula

class(mymdl) <- "rq"
class(mymdl$coefficients) ="numeric"

engel2$foodexp_pr2 <- predict(mymdl, newdata = engel2) #works

#Minor question: why does predict produce NAs in this case?
class(mymdl$terms) = class(mdl$terms)
engel2$foodexp_pr3 <- predict(mymdl, newdata = engel2) #produces NAs
```

I am new to working with classes. Any help and advice is welcome.

**EDIT 1:** I have expanded my example and incorporated your very helpful feedback. `mymdl` is now an "rq"-class. I have also identified the most essential information used by the `predict` function (i.e., `mdl$coefficients` and `mdl$terms`).

**EDIT 2:** Added my solution to the example. However, there is still a minor open question.

Comment: In general, one can either use something like `class(mymdl) <- c("rq", class(mymdl))` to prepend `"rq"` to the vector of class names, though I don't *know* that that is what `rq` expects (I don't have `quantreg` installed). Another option would be to call the specific S3 method, as in `quantreg::predict.rq(mymdl)` (or use `:::` if not exported). Again, I haven't tested that, but those are two ways to get R to use a specific class/S3 method on an object.

Comment: If you print `str(mdl)` and `str(mymdl)` you'll see that your `coefficients` and `terms` components are quite different from the ones produced by `rq()`.  `coefficients` should be a numeric vector, not a list.

Comment: Thanks, adding `class(mymdl$coefficients) ="numeric"` to the code solved the issue. The predict function works!

Comment: A simpler solution is to create it with `mymdl[["coefficients"]] <- c("(Intercept)" = 81.48225,  "income" = 0.5601806)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The S3 class system is very loose. You can make an object be class "rq" just by adding that to its class:

```
class(mymdl) <- "rq"
```

or more generally

```
class(mymdl) <- c("rq", class(mymdl))
```

This doesn't mean that `predict.rq` is going to work; for that you need to check what it needs, and that's not always easy.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have edited my question. Any ideas how I could identify the differences between `mdl` and `mymdl`?